# Second degree differential equation (different method)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation, at initial conditions: $y\left(0\right)=y'\left(0\right)=0$:
$$ y''+y=x \cos \left(2x\right) $$

I've tried the constant variation method, but that leaves me with solving two hard-work integrals for the constant functions:
$$c_1\left(x\right)=∫ -x\sin \left(x\right)\cos \left(2x\right) dx$$
$$c_2\left(x\right)=∫ x\cos \left(x\right)\cos \left(2x\right) dx$$

I can get to the results using Wolfram, but is there another (simpler) way to solve this equation?

Comment: Your integrals aren't that bad with the product-sum identities: $\sin x \cos 2x \equiv \frac 12 (\sin 3x - \sin x)$, for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y''+y=0 \implies r^2+1=0 \implies r=\pm i$$
$$y_h=c_1 \cos (x)+c_2\sin (x)$$

Try this particular solution for the inhomogeneous part:

$$y_p=(Ax+B)\cos(2x)+D\sin(2x)$$

---

Or you can also solve the following equation with the exponential complex:
$$y''+y=xe^{2ix}$$
Try this particular solution for the inhomogeneous equation:
$$ y_p= {(Ax+B) e^{2ix}}$$
You get:
$$-3Ax+(4iA-3B)=x$$
$$ \implies A =-\frac 1 3$$
And for B you find:
$$(4iA-3B)=0 \implies B=\frac {-4i}9$$
Then you have to take the real part of the exponential:
$$y_p=\mathfrak{R} {(Ax+B)e^{2ix}}=\mathfrak{R} { (Ax+B)(\cos(2x)+i\sin(2x))}$$
$$ \boxed {y_p=-\frac 1 3x\cos (2x)+\frac 4 9 \sin(2x)}$$
Finally:
$$y(x)=c_1 \cos (x)+c_2\sin (x)-\frac 1 3x\cos (2x)+\frac 4 9 \sin(2x)$$